# Swift get coordinates of a city by its name

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am trying to get latitude and longitude of a city by its name.
If i enter the city name as "london" my output should be its coordinates

I can get name by coordinates using this code:

```
    var longitude :CLLocationDegrees = 41.0247
    var latitude :CLLocationDegrees = 40.522

    var location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    println(location)



    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        println(location)

        if error != nil {
            println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            println(pm.locality)
        }
        else
        {
            println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse geocoding takes coordinates as input and outputs addresses / administrative levels.

Geocoding does the opposite, which is what you're after. Look at [CLGeocoder's documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009573-CH1-SW9), it's all there.